# convert Json object to java object: The logic

Tags: java, json

I have a json weather API that forecasts five days every three hours. I put part of the json with two forcasts since it is too long and repetitive:

```
{

    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.4194,
    "city": {
        "id": 1851632,
        "name": "Shuzenji",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 138.933334,
            "lat": 34.966671
        },
        "country": "JP",
        "population": 0
    },
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1399950000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 287.82,
                "temp_min": 287.82,
                "temp_max": 287.82,
                "pressure": 923.74,
                "sea_level": 1018.93,
                "grnd_level": 923.74,
                "humidity": 100,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 501,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "moderate rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 92
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 0.51,
                "deg": 226.005
            },
            "rain": {
                "3h": 6
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2014-05-13 03:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1399960800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 291.36,
                "temp_min": 291.358,
                "temp_max": 291.36,
                "pressure": 921.65,
                "sea_level": 1016.09,
                "grnd_level": 921.65,
                "humidity": 87,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 20
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 0.87,
                "deg": 12.0018
            },
            "rain": {
                "3h": 0.5
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2014-05-13 06:00:00"
        },
```

My problem is that I do not understand the logic of making java objects. I used jsongen for generating the java objects, but it seems it does not give me the right objects.
by jsongen my java object classes are:

```
public class Jweather {

        private Number cod;
        private Number message;
        private City city;
        private Number cnt;
        private myList list;
                   ...
                 }

public class City{
    private Coord coord;
    private String country;
    private Number id;
    private String name;
    private Number population;
            ...
           }

public class Coord{
    private Number lat;
    private Number lon;
            ...
           }

public class myList{

    List list = new ArrayList();
    private Number clouds;
    private Number deg;
    private Number dt;
    private Number humidity;
    private Number pressure;
    private Number speed;
    private Temp temp;
    private List weather;
              ...
            }

public class Temp{
    private Number day;
    private Number eve;
    private Number max;
    private Number min;
    private Number morn;
    private Number night;
           ...
         }

public class Weather{
    private City city;
    private Number cnt;
    private String cod;
    private List list;
    private Number message;
            ...
         }
```

I think myList, temp, weather classes are wrong. Am I write or wrong?
I think list.java should contain dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, rain, sys and dt_txt
and I also need a main.java class including: temp, temp_min, temp_max, pressure, sea_level, grnd_level, humidity and temp_kf
and a cloud.java class including: all
and wind class including: speed, deg
and rain class including:3h
and a sys class including: pob

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JSON you pasted in, I agree that the generated classes don't look correct. For example, `morn` does not seem to appear in the JSON at all. Did you paste in the entire JSON content that was used to generate the classes?

What are you using to serialize/deserialize the JSON? `Jackson` is a common framework with which to do that. You would need to define mappers from the beans that store the deserialized JSON to the POJO beans.

I've not used it myself (I use `Jackson` and create the JSON and POJO beans myself), but based on the `json gen` doc, it appears that it's intended to generate the JSON-bean side of things. So you would still need to (at least potentially) define your POJO beans (unless they happened to map 100%, which seems unlikely for a variety of reasons, from different JSON property names versus POJO field names, etc.).

Comment: Yes I pasted all of it and yes I am using jackson.I have written a class to serialize/deserialize for test but it does not work and gives me exception error (Can not deserialize instance of weather.data.myList out of START_ARRAY token) and I think it might be due to mismatch of my java objects and the json

Comment: It's definitely critical for them to match up. Keep in mind the potential for using `@JsonProperty` annotations to map between the actual property names in the JSON itself versus what the field names are in your JSON bean.